# Changing the ActionBar hide animation?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-animation, android-actionbar

By default in Android 3.0+, when ActionBar.hide()/show() are called the bar is animated with a brief fade in/out animation.

There does not seem to be an XML style attribute [in this list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme_actionBarStyle) associated with an animation resource.

Is there some way to change this animation? In my case, I simply want to change the animation time, but is it also possible to have a sliding animation?

Comment: Nowadays it's just `getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No.

At least not in 3.0, 3.1, or 3.2. If you look at the decompiled sources of `com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl` you'll find that the animations are hard-coded.

E.g., from 3.2:

```
.method public hide()V
    .locals 8

    .prologue
    const/4 v5, 0x0

    const/4 v7, 0x0

    const/4 v6, 0x1

    .line 529
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mCurrentAnim:Landroid/animation/Animator;

    if-eqz v2, :cond_0

    .line 530
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mCurrentAnim:Landroid/animation/Animator;

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/animation/Animator;->end()V

    .line 532
    :cond_0
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;->getVisibility()I

    move-result v2

    const/16 v3, 0x8

    if-ne v2, v3, :cond_1

    .line 553
    :goto_0
    return-void

    .line 536
    :cond_1
    iget-boolean v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mShowHideAnimationEnabled:Z

    if-eqz v2, :cond_3

    .line 537
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    const/high16 v3, 0x3f80

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;->setAlpha(F)V

    .line 538
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    invoke-virtual {v2, v6}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;->setTransitioning(Z)V

    .line 539
    new-instance v0, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;-><init>()V

    .line 540
    .local v0, anim:Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    const-string v3, "alpha"

    new-array v4, v6, [F

    aput v5, v4, v7

    invoke-static {v2, v3, v4}, Landroid/animation/ObjectAnimator;->ofFloat(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[F)Landroid/animation/ObjectAnimator;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;->play(Landroid/animation/Animator;)Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;

    move-result-object v1

    .line 541
    .local v1, b:Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContentView:Landroid/view/View;

    if-eqz v2, :cond_2

    .line 542
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContentView:Landroid/view/View;

    const-string/jumbo v3, "translationY"

    const/4 v4, 0x2

    new-array v4, v4, [F

    aput v5, v4, v7

    iget-object v5, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    invoke-virtual {v5}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;->getHeight()I

    move-result v5

    neg-int v5, v5

    int-to-float v5, v5

    aput v5, v4, v6

    invoke-static {v2, v3, v4}, Landroid/animation/ObjectAnimator;->ofFloat(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[F)Landroid/animation/ObjectAnimator;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;->with(Landroid/animation/Animator;)Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;

    .line 544
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    const-string/jumbo v3, "translationY"

    new-array v4, v6, [F

    iget-object v5, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mContainerView:Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;

    invoke-virtual {v5}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;->getHeight()I

    move-result v5

    neg-int v5, v5

    int-to-float v5, v5

    aput v5, v4, v7

    invoke-static {v2, v3, v4}, Landroid/animation/ObjectAnimator;->ofFloat(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[F)Landroid/animation/ObjectAnimator;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;->with(Landroid/animation/Animator;)Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;

    .line 547
    :cond_2
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mHideListener:Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;->addListener(Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;)V

    .line 548
    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mCurrentAnim:Landroid/animation/Animator;

    .line 549
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;->start()V

    goto :goto_0

    .line 551
    .end local v0           #anim:Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet;
    .end local v1           #b:Landroid/animation/AnimatorSet$Builder;
    :cond_3
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl;->mHideListener:Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;

    const/4 v3, 0x0

    invoke-interface {v2, v3}, Landroid/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;->onAnimationEnd(Landroid/animation/Animator;)V

    goto :goto_0
.end method
```

**UPDATE**

Same goes for ICS and JellyBean

Comment: @N.R.S.Sowrabh No. Nor Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 15):

A hack for disabling the ActionBar animation (found by inspecting the source code) can be done through introspection via:

```
try
{
  getActionBar().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(getActionBar(), false);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
  // Too bad, the animation will be run ;(
}
```

Ugly, of course, but this actually work, at least from Android v4.2.

Comment: Freaking awesome! That helped and taught me a lot at the same time ^_^

Answer (score 4):

> if you use support-v7-compat, you can disable hide animation like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //消除动画效果
    disableABCShowHideAnimation(getSupportActionBar());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



public static void disableABCShowHideAnimation(ActionBar actionBar) {
    try
    {
        actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(actionBar, false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        try {
            Field mActionBarField = actionBar.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
            mActionBarField.setAccessible(true);
            Object icsActionBar = mActionBarField.get(actionBar);
            Field mShowHideAnimationEnabledField = icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShowHideAnimationEnabled");
            mShowHideAnimationEnabledField.setAccessible(true);
            mShowHideAnimationEnabledField.set(icsActionBar,false);
            Field mCurrentShowAnimField = icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCurrentShowAnim");
            mCurrentShowAnimField.setAccessible(true);
            mCurrentShowAnimField.set(icsActionBar,null);
            //icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(icsActionBar, false);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither of solutions doesn't work for me so I try this to disable animation at all:

```
public void setActionBarVisible(boolean isVisible) {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int resId;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
        || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        resId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_container", "id", getPackageName());
    } else {
        resId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_container", "id", "android");
    }
    if (resId != 0) {
        decorView.findViewById(resId).setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And it works just fine for me. You can try to animate whole action bar viewGroup to achieve similar effect.

Comment: I've added fix for API21+

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you most certainly can.

You first get the ActionBar view like this:

```
public View getActionBarView() {
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    View v = window.getDecorView();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
    return v.findViewById(resId);
}
```

Then you can apply animations directly on the view like this:

```
View actionbar = getActionBarView();
actionbar.setTranslation(-48); // move it out of the screen
```

Comment: There are no method setTranslation in view

Comment: @Mik you could use setVisibility() instead

Comment: Yes, but it does not help to eliminate or change animation.