# ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock - Smoothly Hide / Show the ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), and attempting to hide / show the ActionBar for fullscreen images, using:

```
getSupportActionBar.hide();
```

and

```
getSupportActionBar.show();
```

But it is really jumpy and awkward. Is there a way to make it smoother, or to apply a translation / opacity animation?

Upon further inspection of ABS source, and through observing its behavior, it seems to have at least a minimal amount of animation defined. The same cannot be said for the standard ActionBar.

Just for completeness, here is the relevant code I'm call from an ImageView.click:

```
if( shouldRender )
{
  . . .

  getSupportActionBar().hide();

  getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
}
else
{
  . . .

  getSupportActionBar().show();

  getWindow().clearFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
}
```

It's worth noting that the flags setting / clearing also causes a jump, but a much less noticeable one, so I was going to tackle it later, if at all.

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439561/420001) (by the creator of ABS) seems to state that it's impossible on a native ActionBar. I suppose I could just edit the two XML files that define his animation, but that will not give me full platform penetration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use an overlay ActionBar

```
 requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERL‌​AY);
```

it doesn't show an animation when `show()`/`hide()` is called.

Comment: What's an overlay ActionBar? Can you provide more info?

Comment: `requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`,

Comment: Official documentation on the subject: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY

Comment: An overlay ActionBar is a fully or partial transparent ActionBar. It is not related with this question but to allow the overlay ActionBar from your styles file put the following in your theme                    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item> 
           <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

Comment: You have to call this before anything else in your onCreate() Method. It works like a charm.