# Jumpy ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i'm implementing an ActionBarSherlock , i want to hide and show my ActionBar due to some events but when i show the ActionBar it glitches and it's jumpy , i've tried setting ActionBarOverlay to true in my ActionBar style and :

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

i've also tried setting `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` in my Activity with no sucess.does anybody know how can i achieve smoothly hide/show my ActionBarSherlock?

Answer (score 1):

Try using overlay as,

```
requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERL‌​AY);
```

Let me know if this helps.

source - [ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock - Smoothly Hide / Show the ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267923/actionbar-or-actionbarsherlock-smoothly-hide-show-the-actionbar)