# Is there a way to disable ActionBar's show/hide animation?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've seen this question:

[Changing the ActionBar hide animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953743/changing-the-actionbar-hide-animation)

But it doesn't say whether it's possible to disable animation altogether.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to disable or skip the animations since they are hardcoded. You could try changing your activity theme to a `NoActionBar` variant if you won't need the action bar at all.

Comment: @ebarrenchea: No, I really need to hide and show the action bar, and animation looks awkward.

Comment: Unfortunately, your only option would be to create your own custom action bar implementation or a look-a-like view for this fragment/activity.

Comment: @IvanMir: Good point.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can now do this,

```
getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It wasn't working for me until I placed it right before showing and hiding...
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

I fixed using the below method:

```
public static void disableShowHideAnimation(ActionBar actionBar) {
    try
    {
        actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(actionBar, false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        try {
            Field mActionBarField = actionBar.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
            mActionBarField.setAccessible(true);
            Object icsActionBar = mActionBarField.get(actionBar);
            Field mShowHideAnimationEnabledField = icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShowHideAnimationEnabled");
            mShowHideAnimationEnabledField.setAccessible(true);
            mShowHideAnimationEnabledField.set(icsActionBar,false);
            Field mCurrentShowAnimField = icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCurrentShowAnim");
            mCurrentShowAnimField.setAccessible(true);
            mCurrentShowAnimField.set(icsActionBar,null);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using private methods is not a very good idea, it will probably get broken in the future. Apple doesn't even allow apps using private methods in the app store.

Comment: @MilošČernilovský Using Android is a bad idea. It's full of bugs and limitations. But I still prefer to hack this hack of an operating system rather than implement things from scratch

Answer (score 4):

If you use ActionBarSherlock then you can do it. See ActionBarImpl class, it has setShowHideAnimationEnabled(boolean enabled) method.

Comment: how to do it in sherlockbar activty ?

Comment: `com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl` is a child of `com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar` Could you give us yourexample of `setShowHideAnimationEnabled(boolean)`, please?