# How to make ActionBar Sherlock invisible/visible?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I know that I could hide and show ABS like:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

However this makes it hide and show with animation and I don't like it. I need it to hide and show immediately like if set visibility property to its view (View.VISIBLE/View.GONE/View.INVISIBLE). How could I achieve that? Or is there a way to hide()/show() without animation (show()/hide() doesn't accept any parameters)? Or is there a way to get ABS view so I could use `setVisibility()` on it?

Comment: If you're using a custom View, have you tried: getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().setVisibility(View.GONE);?

Comment: I'm not, its just common ABS. Besides, I'm afraid that `getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().setVisibility(View.GONE);` gonna hide only the custom view inside ABS but not ABS by itself, so ABS gonna stay visible but empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you can not disable Actionbar show/hide animation.

Comment: It is possible only with *hack* http://stackoverflow.com/a/24739799/2158970 - but I do not recommended this.