# How to clear animation of adding/removing actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

At my application I am using container where I change several fragments. At some fragments I have to hide actionbar at parent activity. I managed to do it, but the process of hiding and viewing toolbar is supported with weird and uncomfortable animation. I hide and show toolbar via:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
```

Maybe I can clear animation?

Comment: try to set view.animate().translationY(0);

Comment: @JohnettMathew, where I have to add this line?

Comment: update-》 getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false); Do this before hiding the actionbar. Please see this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115404/is-there-a-way-to-disable-actionbars-show-hide-animation

Comment: @JohnettMathew, this method can only be called within the same library group, I tried this way of clearing animation, and it didn't help me :(

Comment: What kind of error you get when you tried this?

Comment: @JohnettMathew, I used one answer from this question, and it helped me, thank you so much :)

Comment: If its possible please post the correct answer here. So it might be helpful for someone.

Comment: @JohnettMathew, but what about duplicate??? I used one solution of that question, or I have to insert link after my solution?

Comment: Insert link after the solution so the original author get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for my problem with this method:

```
public static void disableShowHideAnimation(ActionBar actionBar) {
    try
    {
        actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(actionBar, false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        try {
            Field mActionBarField = actionBar.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
            mActionBarField.setAccessible(true);
            Object icsActionBar = mActionBarField.get(actionBar);
            Field mShowHideAnimationEnabledField = icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShowHideAnimationEnabled");
            mShowHideAnimationEnabledField.setAccessible(true);
            mShowHideAnimationEnabledField.set(icsActionBar,false);
            Field mCurrentShowAnimField = icsActionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCurrentShowAnim");
            mCurrentShowAnimField.setAccessible(true);
            mCurrentShowAnimField.set(icsActionBar,null);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115404/is-there-a-way-to-disable-actionbars-show-hide-animation).